# JQuery draggable containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

How to make element draggable over the whole page. Now it only allows me to drag my element within the parent div.

```
 $(thumb).draggable()
```

I am using this librarary: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

```
 var thumb = document.createElement("img");
            $(thumb).draggable({containment: "html"});
            thinner.appendChild(thumb);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(thumb).draggable({containment: "body"});
```

[Official demo on the *containment* option](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

Comment: I'm not sure, but the touchpunch library may be doing something against it in this case?

Comment: I dynamically create an image and apply the dragablle option to it but it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `$(thumb).draggable({containment: "body"});`, then you must add this to the CSS.

```
body{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Otherwise use:

```
$(thumb).draggable({containment: "html"});
```

---

DEMO (Without CSS):
http://jsbin.com/ukotit/7/edit

DEMO (With CSS):
http://jsbin.com/ukotit/5/edit

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work! I can paste a screen shot if you want!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to containment, you may have to use the appendTo option to have your helper appended to the body while you drag it:

```
$(thumb).draggable({containment: "body", appendTo: "body"});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 0):

Try `.draggable({containment: "body", scroll: false})`